# Theorem on friends and strangers: 2 triangles

Tags: graph-theory

According to this problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers

Is it possible to have BOTH 3 strangers and 3 friends at the same time on complete graph of 6 vertices? That is, we have 2 triangles: one of strangers, and the other of friends. I'm in doubt since the illustration on [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers) is unclear in that it shows graphs with 2 triangles, while coloring only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for there to be more than 3 (which I read as 4) mutual friends and 4 mutual strangers at the same time, in a group of 6 people. The proof is straightforward.

Suppose there is a group of 4 mutual friends. Then in particular, each of these four people know each other. Therefore, at most 1 can contribute to a different group of mutual strangers (if 2 are in the mutual strangers group, they would know eachother - whoops). This leaves only 3 people that could be mutual strangers, and 3 is less than 4.